# javascript: What is the shortest way to convert Unix to long date format

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have an ISO time string:

```
"2018-05-14T14:04:53.16"
```

I need to convert it to the following:

```
"May 05, 2018"
```

The way I know is to convert it first to a time stamp using parse, and then new Date:

```
let timestamp = new Date(Date.parse("2018-05-14T14:04:53.16"))
```

Then get each part seperatly, map them to map arrays, and then concating them:

```
let monthNames = ['January','Fabruary'...];
let month = timestamp.getMonth(); //gatDay/getYear
let monthName = monthNames[month - 1]
```

then finaly concating all parts into a string:

```
let finalString = monthName+' '+day+', '+year;
```

Is there a shorter way to do this?
Im asking because both of these date formats are recognized by javascript Date object, yet I cant find a short way to convert between the two.

Comment: `2018-05-14` is May 14, not May 5. `"2018-05-14T14:04:53.16"` is not a unix timestamp. Using MomentJS is recommended in such situations.

Comment: `new Date(Date.parse("2018-05-14T14:04:53.16"))` is identical to `new Date("2018-05-14T14:04:53.16")`. At least one browser in use will not parse 2018-05-14T14:04:53.16 correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert `timestamp` to the desired format with `toString` and some string manipulation:

```
timestamp.toString().replace(/\w+ (\w+ \d+)( \d+).*/, "$1,$2")
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks alot! This is for an angular pipe... didn't think of the regex option.

Comment: The timestamp is already a string, presumably you mean `new Date(timestamp).toString().replace(...)`. The output of *Date.prototype.toString* is implementation dependent and may or may not return the value expected.

Comment: @RobG, I am not sure what you mean with the first point. I am staring at the question and all I can see is that the `timestamp` variable is a `Date` instance, not a string. You are right about the output of `Date.prototype.toString`, but in practice there is a consensus: the output is [always in the American English representation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString) and exactly the same in FF, Chrome, IE11 and Edge. This reflects the EcmaScript2019 draft, where it is no longer defined as implementation specific.

Comment: I probably read too much into the variable name "timestamp", the OP started with "2018-05-14T14:04:53.16", which is a timestamp. It will be a long time before all implementations in use are compliant with the current draft, many devices have limited upgradeability and run older versions. The OP's requirement is really ill-conceived, the goal should be to write compatible, reliable, maintainable code, not the shortest possible.

Comment: @RobG, do you know of any example JS engine that does not produce this output format? NB: Of course I agree with the goal you mention at the end.

Comment: The one in my Samsung TV, which uses an icon similar to Omniweb, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Interesting that in specifying the output of *Date.prototype.toString* and *toUTCString*, the draft ECMAScript 2019 also specifies two more formats that the built-in parser must parse, since the requirement to correctly parse the output of their own *toString* and *toUTCString* methods [*has been retained*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-date.parse).

Answer (score 0):

Alternative(?)

```js
console.log(
new Date("2018-05-14T14:04:53.16").toUTCString().substr(0,12)
)
```

**Performance test!** (Using [benchmark.js](https://github.com/bestiejs/benchmark.js))

```js
var suite = new Benchmark.Suite;

// add tests
suite.add('toUTCString().substr', function() {
  new Date("2018-05-14T14:04:53.16").toUTCString().substr(0,12)
})
.add('Regex', function() {
  timestamp = new Date(Date.parse("2018-05-14T14:04:53.16"))
  timestamp.toString().replace(/\w+ (\w+ \d+)( \d+).*/, "$1,$2")
})
.add('toUTCString().split', function() {
  var d = new Date("2018-05-14T14:04:53.16").toUTCString().split(" ");
    d[2] +  ", " + d[1] + " " +d[3]
})
// add listeners
.on('cycle', function(event) {
  console.log(String(event.target));
})
.on('complete', function() {
  console.log('Fastest is ' + this.filter('fastest').map('name'));
})
// run async
.run({ 'async': true });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/platform/1.3.5/platform.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/benchmark/2.1.4/benchmark.min.js"></script>
```

Update, wrong output. One way, using **split** to recompose:

```js
var d = new Date("2018-05-14T14:04:53.16").toUTCString().split(" ")

console.log(
d[2] +  " " + d[1] + ", " +d[3]
)
```

Comment: But this outputs "Mon, 14 May", not "May 14, 2018"

Comment: The output of *toUTCString* is implementation dependent, so may not return the required format. It also shifts the timezone from local to UTC.

Comment: toLocaleString()

Comment: But instead of downvoting everyone on the page, show us what you can do better ô big master. Or maybe, you should learn to just pass over, Rob i saw you often doing this.

Comment: @Cryptopat—it's a duplicate of many [*similar questions*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+reformat+date+string). I don't get why people keep answering it instead of marking it as a duplicate. If I can make people think a bit more about their answers, them maybe some good will come of it. Or not. :-/

Comment: That's right. Are you advising that stackoverflow should be now read only? Because this is pretty much what you just said.

Answer (score 0):

You can use moment.js as well:

```
var newDate = new moment("2018-05-14T14:04:53.16");
var html = 'Result: <br/>';
html += 'Formatted: ' + newDate.format('MMM DD, YYYY');

$('#output').html(html);
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/okd4mdcw/

Comment: I don't think I'll add another library just for this

Comment: That makes sense  @TKdev, you don't want to pull in moment.js for this specific issue. It's a great library though, keep it in mind!